# PostgreSQL alterar um elemento de uma coluna JSON

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Olá,

Estou tentando alterar uma coluna JSON, porém quero alterar apenas um elemento, no caso, o "url".
Existe algumas urls que possuem os símbolos '^' e '$' no inicio e fim, conforme abaixo:

```
json_avaliado = {"url": "^http://google.com.br$", "data": "2020-09-04T12:00:00.000Z"}
```

Eu gostaria de remover eles, eu consegui filtrar todos os registros que possuem ele, mas não consegui alterar o elemento, tentei usar o "jsonb_set" mas não consegui ainda, segue oque eu tentei até agora:

```
update empresa 
set json_avaliado = jsonb_set(json_avaliado::jsonb, '{url}', substring(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 2, (length(json_avaliado::json->>'url')-2)))
where (left(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 1) = '^' or left(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 1) = '$')
  and (right(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 1) = '^' or right(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 1) = '$')
```

O erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso funciona, não sei pq ele não entender que o substring é um text:

```
set json_avaliado = jsonb_set(json_avaliado::jsonb, '{url}', 'teste')
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Note que ele está indicando o segundo parâmetro (path) como desconhecido. Você tem certeza de que sua cláusula WHERE está certa? Não estão faltando parênteses (AND tem prioridade sobre OR)?

Comment: Oi, sim, mesmo removendo a clausula dá o erro, acredito que é o substring que esteja impactando, pq se eu remover ele e colocar uma string qlqr, funciona. :(

Comment: Você está confundindo as funções `subtring` com `substr`. Veja no manual: `substring( string text [ FROM start integer ] [ FOR count integer ] ) → text` e `substr( string text, start integer [, count integer ] ) → text`.

Comment: Substituindo por 'substr' aparece o mesmo erro :/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema envolvendo o substring dentro da função to_jsonb(), ficando assim:

```
... 
set json_avaliado = jsonb_set(json_avaliado::jsonb, '{url}', to_jsonb(substring(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 2, (length(json_avaliado::json->>'url')-2))))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

O terceiro parametro de `jsonb_set()` espera um objeto do tipo jsonb, mas vc esta passando texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça um cast de `substring(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 2, (length(json_avaliado::json->>'url')-2))` para jsonb q vai fucionar.

```
(substring(json_avaliado::json->>'url', 2, (length(json_avaliado::json->>'url')-2)))::jsonb
```

Confira como usar a funcao corretamente na documentacao: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html